# Need to get the Foreign key value instead of ID in the database table using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

**model**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    client= models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="Client1",default=None)
    user=models.ManyToManyField(Default_User,related_name='users',default=None)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.TextField()                                      #dropdown
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    technical_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    delivery_head_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    class Meta:
        
        db_table ='Project'
    
    
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

**model**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user= models.ForeignKey(Default_User,on_delete=CASCADE)
    project = ChainedForeignKey(Project,chained_field="user", chained_model_field="user",related_name='projects',show_all=False, auto_choose=True, sort=True)
    date = models.DateField(max_length=10,default=None)
    
    class Meta:
        
        db_table ='Job'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.job_name)
```

**serializers**

```
class ProjectSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
      
        model= Project
        fields= '__all__'


class Job_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
      
        model= Job
        fields= ('id','job_name','user','project','date','job',)
```

I need to get the foreign key value displayed in the database table of Job model but as per the above code it is displaying the Foreign key ID. For example I linked the project model in the Job model and in the db table it is showing the Project_id as(1,2,3) but i need to return the values of that id as(app, learning etc). Please help me to get the values of the foreign key value instead of ID in the database table.

Comment: In your job serializer, add `project = ProjectSerializers()`, OR add [`depth = 1`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) in the `Meta`

Comment: I tried both of the method but it dosen't changed anything in the database.

Answer (score 1):

The database will by default take the unique field from the model and django provide id as unique key for models. It is for data consistency. So you can let that happen and in job serializera use SerializerMethodField to retrieve the value of project name based on instance of job objects.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more, i couldn't get the full context. Thanks in advance

Comment: as per the SerializerMethodField i could able to view in the local api but i couldn't able to see the changes in the database table, its still showing the Id's is there any way to change that

Comment: i would still recommend let it be like as it is, use SerializerMethodField  to get the required value each time there is a get request.

Comment: I getting it, but if i do a post call it is not working for that API, it is showing an error as "IntegrityError at /api/Job/   null value in column "project_id" of relation "Job" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (13, API, 2022-03-07, null, null).". But i need to do Post a new data also for that API

Comment: pass the **ID** of project along with other data, when you do a post for job, if not filter the result based on recieved value of project before serializer.save(), and pass the object insatnce in serializer.save("here pass the instance")

Comment: Also try to understand how primary keys work and what are unique keys and foreign keys and how to link tables.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to achieve with it. If it is just to return another field value from project, then you can add it to the serializer as in below example. I am returning project_name as well.

```
class JobSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    job = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    project_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:      
        model= Job
        fields= ('id','job_name','user','project','date','job', 'project_name')
    def get_project_name(self, job):
        return job.project.project_name
```

If you want to return the whole project object then you have to include

> project = ProjectSerializers()