# How to validate foreign key with APIView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm learning django rest framework at school and now I'm on a internship project, I have some doubts using API base View.
I want to do a POST in a endpoint and validate if the foreign key exists or not.
My models:

```
# TABELA DOS FORNECEDORES
class Fornecedor(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    endereco = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    codigo_postal = models.CharField(max_length=8, null=False, blank=False)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    nif = models.IntegerField(
        null=False,
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        validators=[
            RegexValidator(r"[1-9]\d*"),
            MinLengthValidator(9),
            MaxLengthValidator(9),
            MaxValueValidator(999999999),
            MinValueValidator(1),
        ],
    )
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    data_registo = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    data_ultimo_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome

# TABELA DAS MARCAS
class Marca(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=False, blank=False)
    fornecedor = models.ForeignKey(
        Fornecedor, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome
```

My serializers

```
class FornecedorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Fornecedor
        fields = "__all__"


class MarcaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Marca
        fields = "__all__"
```

My views

```
class FornecedorPOST(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary="Criar um Fornecedor",
        operation_description="Criar um novo Fornecedor",
        request_body=FornecedorSerializer,
        responses={
            status.HTTP_201_CREATED: response_201(FornecedorSerializer),
            status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: response_400(FornecedorSerializer),
        },
    )
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        fornecedor = FornecedorSerializer(data=request.data)
        if fornecedor.is_valid():
            fornecedor.save()
            return Response(fornecedor.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(fornecedor.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class MarcaPOST(APIView):
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        operation_summary="Criar uma marca",
        operation_description="Criar uma nova marca",
        request_body=MarcaSerializer,
        responses={
            status.HTTP_201_CREATED: response_201(MarcaSerializer),
            status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST: response_400(MarcaSerializer),
        },
    )
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        marca = MarcaSerializer(data=request.data)
        if marca.is_valid():
            marca.save()
            return Response(marca.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(marca.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    # URLS API ENDPOINTS
    path("api/fornecedor/", views.FornecedorPOST.as_view(), name="add_single_supplier_api"),
    path("api/marca/", views.MarcaPOST.as_view(), name="add_single_brand_api"),

    path("api/docs", schema_view.with_ui("swagger", cache_timeout=0)),
]
```

Basically I want to add new Marca and use nif field from Fornecedor instead of Fornecedor pk and ofc validate if exists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Django rest framework validates a foreign key,
but in case you want to validate any value, you can validate it into view or serializer both ways whichever way you prefer

In this case, I am demonstrating in serializer

```
class MarcaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Marca
        fields = "__all__"
def validate_fornecedor(self, value):
    try:
        code = Fornecedor.objects.get(pk=value)
        return value
    except Refer.DoesNotExist:
        raise serializers.ValidationError('Invalid Fornecedor')
```

Comment: Maybe I do not explay correctly.
I want the validation when I create a new Marca in API.
The body to create Marca is like this:
{
  "name": "Teste",
  "supplier": 1
}

On POST a new Marca I want to use nif instead of pk from Fornecedor and validate them.

Comment: I changed all of my code for english to make it more understandable.
So, now Marca is Brand and Fornecedor is Supplier.

Comment: may I ask why do you want to store nif? If its just you want to return nif then that you can do easily by adding a SerializerMethodField() to the Marca serializer which will return nif of the Fornecedor.

Comment: You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72300722/1568464